# Why does typescript implicitly convert between unrelated classes?

Tags: typescript

Typescript (1.4 & whatever version is powering the typescriptlang.org playground) does not generate a compiler error on code that seems wrong with respect to implicit type conversion of classes that look "similar" in shape.  For instance:

```
class A {
    field: number;
}

class B {
    field: number;
}

function doSomething(a: A): void {
    if (!(a instanceof A))
        throw new Error("Not!")
}

doSomething(new B());
```

This compiles fine and then, of course, results in a runtime error although it seems typing should have prevented the compile.  Similarly I can convert from an interface to a class implicitly without error:

```
interface I {
    field: number;
}

class A implements I {
    field: number;
}

function doSomething(a: A): void {
    if (!(a instanceof A))
        throw new Error("Not!")
}

doSomething({ field: 3 });
```

Breaking the shape similarity by adding a method to the class not already found on the built-in Object in the above example results in the expected compile error instead of the implicit conversion.

```
interface I {
    field: number;
}

class A implements I {
    field: number;

    equals(i: I) {
        return this.field === i.field;
    }
}

function doSomething(a: A): void {
    if (!(a instanceof A))
        throw new Error("Not!")
}

doSomething({ field: 3 });
```

Is this how Typescript is supposed to behave?  Should we not be able to depend on `instanceof` returning an expected value in what seems to be type-safe code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). Classes with identical properties are considered to be identical for the purposes of typechecking. It's better to think of `instanceof` as a runtime check about the prototype chain rather than a statement about what fields an object has or doesn't have.

Comment: Ryan, out of curiosity, since the typescript compiler does have sufficient information, why does it not check this at compile time?

Comment: It does check it. It checks it using a structural type system.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why not a more explicit check? I understand that at runtime the prototype chain is all you have available, but wouldn't it be better to check by actual type at compile time?

Comment: It is an explicit check of the actual type. That check is done using a structural type system.