# TypeScript compiler not enforcing type parameter in implementation of generic interface?

Tags: generics, typescript

Consider a TypeScript interface with two implementations:

```
interface IFoo {}

class FooA implements IFoo {}
class FooB implements IFoo {}
```

Next, consider a generic interface that accepts an implementation of `IFoo` as type parameter:

```
interface IFooHandler<F extends IFoo> {
    handle(foo: F): string
}
```

Now, let's implement the `IFooHandler` interface with a specific implementation of `IFoo` as a type parameter:

```
class FooAHandler implements IFooHandler<FooA> {
    handle(foo: FooB): string {
        return "Hello, Foo A!";
    }
}
```

This compiles perfectly, using `tsc` in version 2.0.3. So here's my question: **Why *does* this compile?**

Note that I've used `FooB` as parameter type in the `FooAHandler`'s `handle()` function. I would assume that this code would trigger a compiler error, as the `IFooHandler<F>` interface prescribes that the `handle` method should accept a parameter of type `F` (so, in case of a `IFooHandler<FooA>`, of type `FooA` -- and **not `FooB`**).

I could not find anything on this behaviour in the TypeScript documentation. Is this behaviour intentional, and if so, what's the reasoning behind it? Or am I just using this feature the wrong way?

---

Just for comparison, implementing the exact same example in Java (omitting the code, as it's quite similar) yields the (expected) compile error:

> FooAHandler.java:1: error FooAHandler is not abstract and does not override abstract method handle(FooA) in IFooHandler

Comment: This is discussed several times in the FAQ - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal and

Comment: Also basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106253/why-does-typescript-implicitly-convert-between-unrelated-classes

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, thanks for the link. Ouch, I cannot believe that I missed the **literally first question** in the FAQ. Anyhow, this behaviour makes more sense to me now! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the compiler doesn't compare the types by name, it checks their structures, and since `IFoo`, `FooA` and `FooB` are all empty then they are all equal.

Even when doing:

```
interface IFoo {
    a: string;
}

class FooA implements IFoo {
    a: string;
}

class FooB implements IFoo {
    a: string;
}
```

The compiler still won't complain, but once we differentiate between `FooA` and `FooB`:

```
class FooA implements IFoo {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

class FooB implements IFoo {
    a: string;
    c: string;
}
```

We get the compiler error:

```
Class 'FooAHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'IFooHandler<FooA>'.  
  Types of property 'handle' are incompatible.  
    Type '(foo: FooB) => string' is not assignable to type '(foo: FooA) => string'.  
      Types of parameters 'foo' and 'foo' are incompatible.  
        Type 'FooA' is not assignable to type 'FooB'.  
          Property 'c' is missing in type 'FooA'.
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFoo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FooA%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FooB%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IFooHandler%3CF%20extends%20IFoo%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20handle(foo%3A%20F)%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FooAHandler%20implements%20IFooHandler%3CFooA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20handle(foo%3A%20FooB)%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20Foo%20A!%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

A side note:
Empty objects (like all of your interfaces) will always accepts everything:

```
interface IFoo { }

function fn(foo: IFoo) {}

fn(3); // ok
fn("string"); // ok
fn({ key: "value" }); // ok
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFoo%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Afunction%20fn(foo%3A%20IFoo)%20%7B%7D%0A%0Afn(3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Afn(%22string%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Afn(%7B%20key%3A%20%22value%22%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok))

Comment: +1, great answer, thanks! I may have actually oversimplified my example, as my actual interfaces of course aren't all empty, but this answer got me on the right track.

Comment: Is there a way to get the originally-expected behavior though?

Comment: @Kir what's the "originally-expected behavior"? If you mean that you want the compiler to compare types by their declared types other than their structure, then no, this is just how the ts compiler works.