# Typescript: Implementing a generic interface

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following generic interface:

```
interface Extractor<T> {
  extractCandidate(): T;
  process(candidate: T): T;
}
```

Conceptually, each `Extractor` implementation is responsible for extracting a particular kind of object from some datasource. The consumer of the `Extractor` can extract a candidate object using `extractCandidate()` or, given any candidate, perform some further processing on it to get a more refined version of the object using `process()`.

Now, let's say I implement an `Extractor` for a class `MyClass`, like so:

```
class MyClass {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

class MyExtractor implements Extractor<MyClass> {
  extractCandidate() {
    //Some dummy logic
    return new MyClass();
  }
  process(candidate) {
    //Some dummy logic
    let res = new MyClass();
    res.a = candidate.a;
    return res;
  }
}
```

Now let's say I instantiate `MyExtractor` and use it:

```
let myExtractor = new MyExtractor();
let processed = myExtractor.process('blah');
```

**Question 1**: Why does this not generate a compile-time error? Based on the definition of the `Extractor` interface, I would expect that the compiler would not allow me to call `myExtractor.process()` with anything but an instance of `MyClass`, or at least with something that is structurally compatible.

**Question 2**: How can I enforce the desired behavior? Do I just need to assert that the `candidate` parameter of `MyExtractor.process()` is of type `MyClass`?

I suspect this has something to do with TypeScript's structural typing system but, after reading [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106253/why-does-typescript-implicitly-convert-between-unrelated-classes) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226246/typescript-compiler-not-enforcing-type-parameter-in-implementation-of-generic-in) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988188/extending-a-generic-parameter-in-typescript) and the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#type-system-behavior), I'm still not sure how it specifically applies here.

My Typescript version is 2.1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted for `MyExtractor` has the following signature for the `process` method:

```
process(candidate: any): MyClass
```

The reason for that is that you haven't specified a type for `candidate` so by default it is `any`.
The compiler won't complain because it satisfies `candidate: T` (as `any` can be `T`).

If you change your code to:

```
process(candidate: MyClass) {
    ...
}
```

Then for:

```
let processed = myExtractor.process('blah');
```

You'll get:

> Argument of type '"blah"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'MyClass'

You can avoid that by using the [--noImplicitAny flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) which will cause the compiler to complain about:

```
process(candidate) {
    ...
}
```

Saying:

> Parameter 'candidate' implicitly has an 'any' type

---

#### Edit

Candidate isn't allowed to be "anything else", it is allowed to be `any` (and that's the default), a good reason for that for example is for overloading:

```
process(candidate: string): MyClass;
process(candidate: MyClass): MyClass;
process(candidate: any) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, but haven't I specified a type *constraint* on `candidate`? In `MyExtractor`, `T` is `MyClass`, so why is `candidate` allowed to be anything else? Indeed, if I assert that the type of `candidate` is `string` and return an empty string, I get the error I expect: "Type '(candidate: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(candidate: MyClass) => MyClass'. Types of parameters 'candidate' and 'candidate' are incompatible. Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: It would be nice if TS could contextually type `process(candidate)` to `process(candidate: MyClass): MyClass` in this case. I've faced similar confusion with how React component definition specifies a type for members, but you can actually implement with incorrect types, its still up to you to give it the correct type in your implementation.

Comment: @Aaron The fact that the interface declares that the method expects a `MyClass` param doesn't necessarily mean that the implementation can't handle other things, which is why the compiler won't make that assumption. To avoid this "problem" simply use `noImplicitAny`, then you'll know when/where you have these sort of cases.